# Niveles de navegación en configuración de zend Framework 3 (laminas)

Tags: php, zend

estoy desarrollando un modulo para ZF3, y en la navegación me gustaría tener subniveles:

```
 'navigation' => [
        'AdminModule' => [
            [
                'label' => 'Prueba',
                'route' => 'admin',
                'resource' => 'Omeka\Controller\Admin\Module',
                'privilege' => 'browse',
         
            'pages' => [
                [
                    'label' => 'Gestión de las cookies', // @translate
                    'route' => 'admin',
                    'resource' => 'Omeka\Controller\Admin\Module',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'subpages'=>[
                        'label' => 'Opción 1',
                        'route' => 'admin',
                        'resource' => 'Omeka\Controller\Admin\Module',
                        'privilege' => 'browse',
                    ],
                   [
                        'label' => 'Opción 2',
                        'route' => 'admin',
                        'resource' => 'Omeka\Controller\Admin\Module',
                        'privilege' => 'browse',
                    ],
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Barra social', // @translate
                    'route' => 'admin',
                    'resource' => 'Omeka\Controller\Admin\Module',
                    'visible' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Modificar css', // @translate
                    'route' => 'admin',
                    'resource' => 'Omeka\Controller\Admin\Module',
                    'visible' => true,
                ],
                [
                    'label' => 'Constructor por bloques', // @translate
                    'route' => 'admin/easy-install',
                    'resource' => 'Omeka\Controller\Admin\Module',
                    'visible' => true,
                    'privilege' => 'browse',
                ],
            ],
            
        ],
```

Pueden observar que me gustaría disponer de un subnivel llamado por ejemplo **subpages,** que me permitiera disponer de un menú de configuración a mi gusto, ¿Alguien puede indicarme como configurar este array de configuración?.

Gracias.